# What am I doing wrong with using the this keyword and loops with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I think that only my html and my javascript should be necessary for this example. Basically, I am trying to make the elements have something happen to them in CSS in JS with a delay. However, I am unable to seem to get the setTimeout feature to get it to work. I am well aware of the Jquery delay function, but, I want to be able to do it in JavaScript. This is my HTML and this is my JS.

```js
let div1 = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (i = 0; i < div1.length; i++) {
  div1[i].addEventListener('click',
    function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        this[i].style.display = "none";
      }, 200)
    },
    false);
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/csstest.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="grid">
    <div class="img1">aaaa</div>
    <div class="img2">bbbb</div>
    <div class="img3">cccc</div>
    <div class="img4">dddd</div>
    <div class="img5">eeee</div>
    <div class="img6">ffff</div>
    <div class="img7">gggg</div>
    <div class="img8">hhhh</div>
  </section>

  <script src="../JS/testjs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `this` inside setTimeout callback function refers to the global object window, and not to what you may expect, you need to store it in a variable or use an arrow function to preserve the value of `this`

Comment: `setTimeout(() => {` or `setTimeout(function() {
        this.style.display = "none";
      }.bind(this), 200)`

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` inside setTimeout callback function refers to the global object window, and not to what you may expect, you need to store it in a variable or you can use an arrow function to preserve the context of `this`

**Using a variable to store it**

```js
let div1 = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (i = 0; i < div1.length; i++) {
  div1[i].addEventListener('click',
    function() {
      let self = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        self.style.display = "none";
      }, 200);
    },
    false);
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/csstest.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="grid">
    <div class="img1">aaaa</div>
    <div class="img2">bbbb</div>
    <div class="img3">cccc</div>
    <div class="img4">dddd</div>
    <div class="img5">eeee</div>
    <div class="img6">ffff</div>
    <div class="img7">gggg</div>
    <div class="img8">hhhh</div>
  </section>

  <script src="../JS/testjs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Using an arrow function**

```js
let div1 = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (i = 0; i < div1.length; i++) {
  div1[i].addEventListener('click',
    function() {
      setTimeout(_ => this.style.display = "none", 200)
    },
    false);
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/csstest.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="grid">
    <div class="img1">aaaa</div>
    <div class="img2">bbbb</div>
    <div class="img3">cccc</div>
    <div class="img4">dddd</div>
    <div class="img5">eeee</div>
    <div class="img6">ffff</div>
    <div class="img7">gggg</div>
    <div class="img8">hhhh</div>
  </section>

  <script src="../JS/testjs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```